# AngularJS, ng-repeat + filter to be called from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a tricky question

html:

```
ng-repeat="item in obj.Items | filter:someFilter"
```

JS:

```
$scope.someFilter = function (item) { ... }
```

which works. But the problem is, I need to be able to manually invoke the `someFilter` somewhere inside in controller.

OK, I know I can do the `$filter("someFilter")(...)` but that filter requires an `item object` from the `ng-repeat`. So, how can I provide that argument ?

Comment: Not sure if I get this correctly, but if you need to call the `someFilter` function, you can just do `$scope.someFilter()` any time after it has been declared.

Comment: share the exact scenario where you need this! Its difficult to interpret what exactly u needed!

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code below for the issue raised:

```
angular.forEach(obj.Items, function (key, value) {
    $scope.someFilter(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a filter in two ways.

- As a function of `$scope`.It's your way.
- Create your own filter.

In the second case, when you call `$filter`, then as a parameter you will need to pass an **array** to filter your items.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/3stsg4L4/)

```
<form name="ExampleForm">
  Filter by $scope function fillArr
  <div ng-repeat="a in arr|filter:fillArr">
    {{a}}
  </div>
   Filter by filter filArrFilter
  <div ng-repeat="a in arr|filArrFilter">
    {{a}}
  </div>
    Filtered in $scope manualy
  <div ng-repeat="a in filteredArr">
    {{a}}
  </div>
</form>
```

And JS controller

```
$scope.arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8];
$scope.fillArr = function(item) {
  return item % 2 == 0;
}
$scope.filteredArr = $filter('filArrFilter')($scope.arr);
```

And JS filter

```
.filter('filArrFilter', function() {
return function(items) {
  var result = [];
  angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
    if (item % 2 == 0)
      result.push(item);
  });
  return result;
}
})
```